# Layout Issue with the last row of GridView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

Here is my GridView. I have 3 items in each row.

[image]

As shown in the picture, the last row in the view contains only one item. If the last row contains 3 items, the grid view scrolls properly till the end. If the last row has less than 3 items the view doesn't scroll more than what is shown in the picture. GridView ignores the row which is not filled completely. What could be the reason for this?

Note: It works fine if I add invisible dummy items at the end to fill the row.

This is my GridView layout.

```
 <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view_featuredtab"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:columnWidth="190dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
            android:listSelector="@color/gridviewlistselector"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
            android:verticalSpacing="3dp" >
```

Comment: Is it OK that with android:numColumns="1" three columns are actually shown?  Would android:numColumns="auto_fit" make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, tackled it by adding dummy hidden row of items at the end.