# Android Gridview Lastrow does not appear fully

Tags: android, gridview

I have problem with my gridview, last row seems to be cut in the layout when there is only one column however when there are 3 columns the row is completely visible.
Kindly refer the below post which is similar to my problem 
[Layout Issue with the last row of GridView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286009/layout-issue-with-the-last-row-of-gridview-in-android/28600513#28600513).

My gridview layout xml posted below,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relfavViews"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:minHeight="50dp">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/grid_view_fav"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:columnWidth="100dip"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dip"></GridView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Can anyone explain the reason or provide me a fix for the issue. In my case im using Gridview inside a Swiperefreshlayout. Would that be any problem ??

Comment: The OP of the linked post also answered his own question with a workaround.

Comment: hi can u try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710493/gridview-return-only-one-row/22727503#22727503

Comment: @Arun :  tough luck i have implemented custom gridview mentioned in your post but it does not seem to work, i have been using grtidview under SwipeLayout FYI just thinking that might be creating the problem

Comment: Hi why you are using swipeLayout can u try your code by removing that

Comment: @Arun : i tried removing Swipelayout but the problem still exists,  any other thing i would have missed ??

Comment: How you used my answer ,did u give all the properties u given above in my custom gridview

Comment: for working custom gridview the height should be wrap content

Comment: I have used all your properties but no success, please find below my latest xml code .. ' 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:columnWidth="100dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
       '